# How to pass query string in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest

I making form where listing is done and also placing some filters like price, model. The data is coming from json and I am using like

```
$scope.getCarResource = $resource(urls, {}, {
      query: {method:'GET',headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json'},cache:true,maxAge:3500000,params:{keyword:'@keyword',make:'@make',nit:'@nit'}}
    })`
```

Now I want to pass the url like this www.example.com?keyword=abc&make=233&nit=3
 so how to pass 3 or more parameters in url so that it can fetch data from example.com
also I am using $routeParms and whenever I say $routeParams.keyword it gives undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query parameters will be passed in second parameter in $resource method. This will append three query string parameter to your urls variable.

```
  $scope.getCarResource = $resource(urls, {keyword: 'abc', make: 233, nit: 3}, {
          query: {method:'GET',headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json'},cache:true,maxAge:3500000,params:{keyword:'@keyword',make:'@make',nit:'@nit'}}
        })
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply but the parameters are dynamic say for coming from html so how to achieve it?
even I created a function like 
$scope.getList = function($routeParams) { $scope.data = $scope.getCarResource.query({keyword:$routeParams}); }
but I want it for 3 parameters.

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean by dynamic and coming from HTML? You just need to replace your hard values with view values. what else?

Comment: dynamic means suppose there is text box in html and if user enters value say for abc and press button it will call getList('params') then the value will be abc. I hope you understand.

Comment: just replace hard 'abc' value with your view text box value, when you call above method

Comment: how to do it I am new to angularjs so I don't know I tried to write like this keyword: '@keyword' but nothing happens.

Comment: I am integrating this with drupal so the code will not run but you'll get the idea
http://plnkr.co/edit/UncH9ovzQiuMrSjda1rK?p=info

Comment: so if I want to add multiple parameters I'll just add after keyword separated by comma?

Comment: Yes.. you don't even need to define in $resource method. Just pass it when you call $resource.query. It will be added into your query string. BTW.. did above plnkr worked for you?

Comment: Thanks, Yes It's working but in html there are 2 elements texbox and select(dropdown list) so on button click and changing event of select I have to call my method?

Comment: In that case individual parameters are added not together!!